# Permission error when trying to debug on iPhone

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin-studio

I'm trying to debug my Xamarin Studio project on iPhone.
I did all the steps for creating provisioning profile file on [this document](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/device_provisioning/).
So I have created the provisioning profile
but I cannot debug on iPhone.

Xamarin Studio gets this error:

> error MT1006: Could not install the application '...iOS.app' on the device: Permission Error (error: 0xe800000a).

Note :
I'm trying with iPhone 4S and running IOS 7.0 on it,
Xamarin Studio version: 6.0 (build 5174),
Xcode version: 7.3.1

Comment: This topic can be related : https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/8134/could-not-install-the-application-on-the-device-your-application-failed-code-signing-checks

Comment: make sure you have added your iPhone in selected provisioning profile

Comment: How can I add iPhone to provisionin profile ? You are right, I have just seen my provision profile doesn't have attached device on Apple Member Center / Provision Profiles when I select and check the detail.

Comment: I have added iPhone to provision profile, but still have the same error

Comment: I have added iPhone to Development profile. But my Distributon profile has not attacted device. Is it the reason for this error?

Comment: It is possible and also you need to download certificate and install again after changed done.

Comment: can you please check in your iPhone have installed same app that signing with distribution provisional profile. if yes then remove already installed app and try to install new version from your system

Comment: I now have a single distribution profile but still have the error.